# Not able to add relational data to a collection type from post request in strapi v4

Tags: javascript, post, strapi, headless, headless-cms

So I can add the relational data from the admin panel in strapi, so in this case there is a collection type called reviews and it has many to one relationship with another collection type called products

In postman when I add a review I’m not able to add relation to it. Currently I’m adding the relation via id as that is the standard.

I was able to do in this in v3, but in strapi v4 for some reason the relation is not getting added.

Comment: Hey @Siemen_Subbaiah, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I could not get the solution at that time and I reverted back to v3!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by going to "Settings" > "Users  permissions plugins" > "Roles" > "Public" (or "Authenticated", depending on if you want only logged-in users to access it) > "Products" and click "find" and "findOne" and save it.

If "find" and "findOne" in a collection aren't enabled for "Public" or "Authenticated" users, then Strapi won't bother finding the id in the collection that the relation is referring to because you haven't allowed those users to access that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution (fix the relation) + add find permission
https://youtu.be/5miTxxBqSOM?t=75